# What is the appropriate action if a question has been incorrectly marked as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

A while ago one of my [question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/88801/can-my-character-build-an-atom-bomb)s was, I believe, incorrectly marked as a duplicate. Regardless of this particular case, what are one's options if they have a question incorreclty considered a duplicate other than writing a new question with a different wording?

Comment: Ironic that a query inquiring about a query about being closed as duplicate has now been closed as duplicate!

Comment: And once again it is not a duplicate, mine is a general question, it does not refer to a specific case like the others

Comment: *This* question (here in Meta) is a duplicate. Hence the irony. If you had read my comments on your original question, you'd see that I do not concur that the query on Main is a duplicate. It has other problems which I addressed.